# Set part of string equal to part of array

Tags: javascript

I want to set a part of a string equal to part of an array. Basically the following is what I've attempted:

```
var x=[4,6,9,2];
var y="hello";
// y[0] is h; y[1] is e; and so on
y[0] = x[2];
alert(y);
// should alert 9ello; but it doesn't, any ideas?
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable. The array notation can only be used to get characters, but not to set them.

You should split the string into an array of characters, and join it back at the end.

```
y = y.split(''); // ["h","e","l","l","o"]
y[0] = x[2];     // ["9","e","l","l","o"]
y = y.join('');  // "9ello"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace and put the results in a new string:

```
var x=[4,6,9,2];
var y="hello";
var z= y.replace(y[0], x[2]);
alert(z);
```

Or without creating a new string:

```
var x=[4,6,9,2];
var y="hello";
alert (y.replace(y[0], x[2]) );
```